# J2ME API Hard to Find

Tags: api, file, java-me

Where is the API for J2ME? Why is it more difficult to find J2ME's API than its J2SE counterpart? Typing String and Java 1.6 will immediately present one with the String Javadoc for J2SE 6, but doing a similar thing for J2ME will present one with a specific phone manufacturer's Javadoc.

I am particularly looking for javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection, but I am unable to find it on SUN Java's [website](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis.jsp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some J2ME javadocs' can be found at [gotapi](http://www.gotapi.com), and you can always download the jsr documentation at the [java community process](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview) site.

Another resource I found is the [j2me page on mobilezoo](http://mobilezoo.biz/j2me.php) (ie. the api you are looking for, the [jsr 75](http://mobilezoo.biz/jsr/75/fileconnection/index.html)).

I think that Sun doesn't keep these javadocs because they are out of their control. But sure the jcp guys should maintains a browsable version of the specifications.

Comment: Even though I could not find the FileConnection JavaDoc on gotapi, it is a good reference for further work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because the class is in an 'optional' package.

You can download the specification and javadoc from http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75

Answer (score 1):

The official Java ME API documents can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis.jsp).